# Spring boot Cloud SQL with Kubernetes engine GKE Google Cloud

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have created a spring boot project which connects with Cloud SQL(MySQL).
I have deployed this in google cloud (cloudrun) and it is working in it.

now, I am trying to deploy the same container image of spring boot app in kubernates enigne GKE and i am expecting this will connect with mysql cloud sql instance.
however, i am getting below errors in application POD logs.

---

```
     "method" : "google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SqlInstancesService.CreateEphemeral"
      "service" : "sqladmin.googleapis.com",
    "metadata" : {
    "domain" : "googleapis.com",
    "reason" : "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
    "@type" : "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
  "details" : [ {
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED",
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  } ],
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "domain" : "global",
  "errors" : [ {
  "code" : 403,

Failed to create ephemeral certificate for the Cloud SQL instance.
```

---

please help on this...what could be the solution

Comment: any update on this ? please update the status.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are passing the service account file but you can pass it using the **Kubernetes** secret or use the **Service account** and attach it to deployment.

```
kubectl create secret generic google-application-credentials --from-file=./application-credentials.json
```

Deployment volume in which secret get attached

```
volumes:
- name: google-application-credentials-volume
  secret:
    secretName: google-application-credentials
    items:
    - key: application-credentials.json # default name created by the create secret from-file command
      path: application-credentials.json
```

Mount secret at the path

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-service
    volumeMounts:
    - name: google-application-credentials-volume
      mountPath: /etc/gcp
      readOnly: true
```

At last, you can pass the environment variables which will point to this file and cred

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-service
    env:
    - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
      value: /etc/gcp/application-credentials.json
```

Make sure your service account has sufficient role to update Cloud SQL.